# replace string in a file

Tags: sed

I need to replace a string in 14th to 20th position in a file with input value

String = A2245 4764ABC0000342

string to be replace = 0000342 with 0000992

I tried using sed but did not work.

Comment: ...and quite a bunch of others

Comment: If you need help with commands, post the exact command you ran and the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `sed` with the `-i` command to edit in place.

Example:

```
$ cat testfile
A2245 4764ABC0000342

$ sed -i 's/0000342/0000992/' testfile

$ cat testfile
A2245 4764ABC0000992
```

Hope this helps!